# RefreshControl 'stealing' move gesture from ViewPagerAndroid

Tags: android, android-viewpager, react-native, scrollview

If I have a `ViewPagerAndroid` inside of a `ScollView` with `RefreshControl` enabled, the `RefreshControl` will steal the pan movement from the `ViewPagerAndroid`.

What I mean is, by dragging the `ViewPager` to the left midway and then, without releasing the touch, start to drag down, the `RefreshContorl` will activate, appearing and resetting the state of the `ViewPager`.

[image]

I tried to disable the `RefreshControl` as soon as the `ViewPager` returns something other than idle, but if the swipe is quick enough (which usually is), the update does not happen on time to stop the `RefreshControl` from appearing.

My layout is as simple as possible:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }} removeClippedSubviews={true}>
      <View style={{ height: 500, width: 350, marginBottom: 15, backgroundColor: 'cyan' }}>
        <ViewPagerAndroid style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <View><Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>{'Page1'}</Text></View>
          <View><Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>{'Page2'}</Text></View>
        </ViewPagerAndroid>
      </View>
      <View style={{ height: 500, width: 350, marginBottom: 15, backgroundColor: 'lightblue' }}>
        <ViewPagerAndroid style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <View><Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>{'Page1'}</Text></View>
          <View><Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>{'Page2'}</Text></View>
        </ViewPagerAndroid>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
```

I'm using a Mac, react-native version 0.27.2

Answer (score 0):

You're having ViewPagerAndroid in ScrollView, it should be the other way round.

btw. I'm using [scrollable tabview](https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view) with refreshcontrol and it works well. It doesn't use ViewPagerAndroid, as far as I know, but it's crossplatform and performs well (after disabling dev mode and reloading).

Comment: The ViewPagerAndroid is part of the scrollable content. How could I achieve this if the Pager is outside of the ScrollView? I have explored other JS-based options such as the one you linked to, but the performance is noticeably worse ...

Comment: sorry, looking at the gif I thought you wanted to achieve having multiple scrollviews, not just one. Have you tried putting something above the ViewPagerAndroid so that the `scrollY` is not at 0?